# Como excluir uma linha qualquer de um data frame no R?

Tags: r, data.frame

Tenho um data frame da seguinte maneira:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

como faço para remover a primeira linha?

Comment: não entendi muito bme, a primeira linha do que? se possivel coloque o código não uma imagem.

Comment: Fernando, bem vindo ao SOpt, acesse a Ajuda e faça o Tour. Apesar da pergunta parecer clara, acredito que você possa melhorá-la esclarecendo mais as suas dificuldades ou tentativas (mais detalhamentos), assim aqueles que poderão te ajudar terão mais conteúdo para isso. Edite sua pergunta para tanto.

Answer (score 5):

Para excluir uma linha do `data.frame` você deve **não selecionar** aquela linha e sobrescrever seu `data.frame`.

Por exemplo, usando os dados do `data.frame` da sua imagem:

```
notas.inform <- data.frame(nros = c(2355, 3456, 2334, 5456),
                           turma = c("tp1", "tp1", "tp2", "tp3"),
                           notas = c(10.3, 9.3, 14.2, 15.0))
```

Se você quiser excluir a primeira linha de `notas.inform`, basta selecionar todas as linhas menos a primeira e sobrescrever `notas.inform`:

```
notas.inform <- notas.inform[-1, ] # deleta a primeira linha
notas.inform
  nros turma notas
2 3456   tp1   9.3
3 2334   tp2  14.2
4 5456   tp3  15.0
```

Comment: Adicionando, você pode excluir multiplas linhas utilizando colocando identificando elas em um vetor. e.g.: `notas.inform[-c(1,2,3),]`  retornaria o data-frame `notasinform` sem as linhas 1,2 e 3.